# What does the error message "sda access beyond end of device virtualsda access beyond end of device" in a virtualboxbox system?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, virtualbox

Today I tried to turn off one of my VirtualBox system and I got that error over and over again for a few minutes. Then I just forced a shutdown.

I remember that I resized that partition from 50G to 100G. It looks like the `resize2fs` did run properly. What I'm wondering is how can I test that the partition size is correct? There is no LVM. I have just one partition (`/dev/sda2`), although there is a something grub uses in `/dev/sda1`.

I was able to successfully shutdown after that kill because I wanted to test with `fsck`. But that gives me nothing. It says everything is fine. I also checked with GParted and again that everything looks just fine...

The file system is ext4.

The following is the output of the GParted **Check** command:

```
GParted 1.3.1

configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

libparted 3.4

========================================
Device: /dev/sda
Model:  ATA VBOX HARDDISK
Serial: VBcf2fb2fe-c06ce5e1
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  209715200
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  411206
 
Partition table:    gpt
 
Partition   Type    Start         End       Flags       File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sda1   Primary  2048        4095       bios_grub   grub2 core.img      
/dev/sda2   Primary 4 096   209713151                   ext4        

========================================
Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sda2  00:00:06    ( SUCCESS )
        
calibrate /dev/sda2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sda2 (partition)
start: 4096
end: 209713151
size: 209709056 (100.00 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda2 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:06    ( SUCCESS )
        
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/sda2'  00:00:06    ( SUCCESS )
        
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

190379 inodes used (2.90%, out of 6553600)
2046 non-contiguous files (1.1%)
172 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 183008/217
10998005 blocks used (41.96%, out of 26213632)
0 bad blocks
4 large files

152650 regular files
30353 directories
7 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
123 links
7359 symbolic links (7138 fast symbolic links)
1 socket
------------
190493 files
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
resize2fs -p '/dev/sda2'  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
resize2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
The filesystem is already 26213632 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!
```

Any idea why the error occurred and whether my data is at risk?